# Calculating time difference in minutes between a date and a timestamp columnn

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, data-science

I cant seem to figure out what I am doing wrong,
I have 2 columns in my df that look like below,

```
    Date                Time 
2019-07-23 21:17:47.599  22:00:00.000
2019-07-23 21:11:46.973  21:50:00.000
```

I want to create a new column in the df that calculates the difference in minutes between these two columns. I am trying 2 methods that aren't working.

First method is where I use `pd.to_timedelta(pd.to_datetime(df3.Time)-pd.to_timedelta(df3.Date).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')) / np.timedelta64(1, 'm')`

If I try this I get an error of `ValueError: only leading negative signs are allowed`

Second method I am trying is where I convert the Date column by doing

```
df3['new_time'] = [d.time() for d in df3['Date']]
```

that gives me a timestamp such as `22:25:03.895000`

I then use `(pd.to_datetime(df3.Time) - pd.to_datetime(df3.new_time))`

The error I am getting using that is `TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime`

I am not sure what I am missing or not doing correctly, but is there a way where I can correctly have a new column that gives me the value in minutes of Time - Date?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, only cannot convert `Time` column to `datetime`s, but only to `timedelta`s and if there are python object times first cast to strings:

```
df3['new'] = ((pd.to_timedelta(df3.Time.astype(str))- 
               pd.to_timedelta(df3.Date.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))) /
                 np.timedelta64(1, 'm'))
print (df3)
                     Date          Time        new
0 2019-07-23 21:17:47.599  22:00:00.000  42.216667
1 2019-07-23 21:11:46.973  21:50:00.000  38.233333
```

Comment: Thank you!, what was I doing wrong previously? did i need to convert to timedelta ?